# How to use Open Street Map API in Google spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, openstreetmap

in Google Spreadsheet with this formula

```
=importxml("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/xml?origin=" & E5 &
"&destination=" & F5 & "&sensor=false&alternatives=false","//leg/distance/value")
```

I can calculate distance between two address written in cell E5 and F5 with Google Maps API.

Is there a way to use Open Street Map instead of Google api?

I tried to read the documentation but I did not found a solution.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The [OSM API](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/API) is mainly used for *editing* OSM data. It doesn't provide any routing functionality itself. But there are many third-party [OSM-based online routers](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Routing/online_routers) you can use, such as [graphhopper](http://graphhopper.com/), [OSRM](http://project-osrm.org/) and many more.